# colsum rowsum populating matrix

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, apply

I'm trying to write for each cell entry in a matrix what value is smallest, either its rowsum value or colsum value in a new matrix of the same dimension.

For example:

say I have matrix c which looks like this:

```
x <- matrix(seq(1:6),2)
x
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

Its rowsum and colsum are:

```
rowSums(x)
[1]  9 12
colSums(x)
[1]  3  7 11
```

so based on that info, the new matrix should look like this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    7    9
[2,]    3    7    11
```

I've been thinking about using apply but I do not know how I can write an if statement to write the smallest value from either rowsum or colsum for each cell entry. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't `x[1,3]` be a 9?

Comment: yes, you're right. I'll fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be thought of as an outer product of the row and column sums, where the function takes the minimum value:

```
outer(rowSums(x), colSums(x), FUN=pmin)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    3    7    9
## [2,]    3    7   11
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x[] <- pmin(rep(colSums(x), each = nrow(x)), rep(rowSums(x), times = ncol(x)))
x
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    7    9
# [2,]    3    7   11
```